# write lines on PDF

Tags: pdf, pdfsharp, cgpdfdocument

I want to write line by line on a pdf document
the code I have is writing the text in the center of the page
how can I write line by line?

```
// Create a new PDF document
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

// Create an empty page
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

// Get an XGraphics object for drawing
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

// Create a font
XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

// Draw the text
gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
               new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
               XStringFormats.TopCenter);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height)` you specify where text will be drawn.
Use a smaller rectangle and increase the second value from line to line.

PDFsharp includes several examples:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx
Especially check Text Layout. Sample code included with the source package of PDFsharp.

Also check out MigraDoc as it adds pagebreaks automatically.
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocSamples.ashx